# Find $\sigma$ for which $\sum _{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{a_i\cdot a_{\sigma(i)}}$ is maximal

Tags: abstract-algebra, summation, permutations

$$\text{Let: } 0 < a_1 \lt a_2 \lt \dots \lt a_n$$

$$\text{Find } \sigma \in S_n \text{ for which :}$$

$$\sum _{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{a_i\cdot a_{\sigma(i)}} \text{ is maximal}$$

I think the maximum value of the sum will be reached if $\sigma = e$ but i don't know how to prove that. Any idea is really appreciated! Thanks for help!

*Note:* $e = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & ... & n\\
1 & 2 & ... & n
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: $e$ the euler's constant ?

Comment: Ok it's clearer now .

Comment: @Mister.Expandead Edited. Thanks. In my book, $e = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & ... & n\\
1 & 2 & ... & n
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Have you tried induction, starting with $n=2$ and then using an inversion to fix $n+1$ during the induction step?

Comment: look at wiki entry of [rearrangement inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality). In particular, the proof there.

Comment: My first try would be $a_i=\frac{1}{x_i}$ and then use https://brilliant.org/wiki/rearrangement-inequality/

Comment: Thank you all! Easily solved with rearrangement inequality. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Cauchy Schwarz inequality
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{a_ia_{\sigma(i)}} \leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{a_i^2}\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{a_{\sigma(i)}^2}\right)^{1/2}=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{a_i^2}$$
The equality occurs when $a_i=\lambda a_{\sigma(i)}$ for all $i$. This would mean that $$\prod_ia_i=\lambda^n \prod_{i}a_{\sigma(i)}=\lambda^n\prod_ia_i \implies \lambda=1$$

Thus $\sigma$ is the identity permutation.